# display custom pop-up in vtiger crm

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I want to Display a pop-up box when a user opens a contact whose first name is a palindrome and whose last name is a semordnilap in vtiger crm .

Comment: Seems like you need a little more information in this post.  Also, please include what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open popup on edit view or detail view you can use [Jqueryconfirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) library.

```js
$.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Simple confirm!',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            $.alert('Confirmed!');
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Canceled!');
        },
        somethingElse: {
            text: 'Something else',
            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
            action: function(){
                $.alert('Something else?');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Write jQuery functions on the event by using the functions which are shown in documentations as per your requirement.